# Popup window appearing while stopping the C process

Tags: java, c++, c

I am calling a C process from my Java program, and ending that C process using exit (0).

On Windows machine, under certain conditions it is opening a pop-up window telling me that 
"Test.exe has encountered a problem and needs to close.  We are sorry for the inconvenience."

Does anyone have a guess why this problem is coming around? I want a clean shutdown without any window being opened.

I have used below alternatives also to close, with the same result:

```
exit(EXIT_SUCESS);
```

and

```
return 0;
```

Comment: It is crashing..what is the statement just above return?

Comment: You could obviously use a debugger to attach to your C process. From your post it sounds like you are writing both parts (Java and C).

Answer (score 4):

The `exit` or `return` isnt likely to be the issue - the problem is a memory overrun etc. within the exe. You need to debug that when the problem happens.